# Convert a date in R that can be used in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Currently my data has dates in the format "Jan2000".  How do I change it to be more ggplot friendly?  I want to make a time series graph.  Thank you!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [zoo package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html), e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

test <- c("Jan2000", "Feb2020")
as.yearmon(test)
#>[1] "Jan 2000" "Feb 2020"

dates <- seq(as.yearmon(test)[1],
             as.yearmon(test)[2],
             length.out = 100)
values <- rbinom(n = 100, size = 10, prob = 0.5)
data <- tibble(dates, numbers)

ggplot(data, aes(x = dates, y = values)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: example.png]